# get data from more than one subcollection at the same time in firestore

Tags: kotlin, firestore

Tengo una bbdd en firestore en la que tengo una collection users en la que los datos son simplemente el identificador de cada usuario. Por cada usuario tengo una subcollection marcadores (de google) en la que para cada marcador guardo distintos datos.
ejemplo:
db.collection("users").document(userEmail)
.collection("markers").document(marker1)

¿ Como puedo listar todos los marcadores de todos los usuarios?

He probado con collectionGroup pero con eso podria obtener toda la coleccion users pero no la subcoleccion markers...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Se trata de una app en la que cada usuario se loga, puede poner marcadores de ubicaciones en un mapa y puede ver las ubicaciones creadas por los demas usuarios. pero si en la bbdd quiero poner una colleccion de usuarios y dentro de cada usuario sus marcadores, como podria entrar desde la cuenta de un usuario "x" a un marcador concreto de un usuario "y" sin conocer el id del documento usuario del creador y propietario de ese marcador.